# Is fastclick js still needed?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, click, responsive

I mean this:

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Is it still needed and important?

I know there are things related to viewport declarations concerning certain browsers. But It seems they are old things, and what about the other browsers nowadays?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this, but at the same time this question feels rather opinion based.

Comment: How about making some tests? http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/examples/layer.html

Comment: Opinion based? Tap delay is not an opinion, is (was) a mobile "feature". See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This article explains in detail why and when you need `fastclick.js`:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

**TL;DR**

> As of Chrome 32 (back in 2014) this delay is gone for mobile-optimised sites, without removing pinch-zooming! Firefox and IE/Edge did the same shortly afterwards, and in March 2016 a similar fix landed in iOS 9.3.

As long as your `<head>` includes: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`, this way the browser assumes you have made the text readable on mobile so there is no need for double-click.